# Do some routers not support 2-way UDP communications?

Tags: networking, router, udp

I have Windows apps I've written to send commands (client) to a server app that returns some data via UDP. This works on a local LAN but when I put the server software at a data center, the server receives the command but nothing comes back. I have to specifically open the port in the router before it will let the reply come back. I thought routers would temporarily allow return communication. Can someone help?

Comment: This is really a matter of firewalls, not of routing; but Does the reply come back from the same IP address and source port as the original request was sent to? (And do _both_ the request and the reply travel through the same router?)

Comment: Sounds like a great question for SO provided there is a MRE you can provide.

Comment: when you say you have to "specifically open the port in the router" describe how you do that (is it firewall, or NAT or something else that you are configuring?

Comment: > Does the reply come back from the same IP address and source port as the original request was sent to?

That's a good question. The server has 3 IP addresses and I'm sending to one of those addresses. I suspect I have to set a binding on the server software.

Answer (score 0):

When packets are send from inside the network to some external server the NAT router create an association (state) based for the UDP "connection", i.e. for the tuple of `(client_ip,client_port,server_ip,server_port)`. Only replies which match this tuple will be forwarded to the internal client, since no such association is known for other incoming packets.

> I have to specifically open the port in the router

This wording suggests that there is a fixed port where the server is sending the reply back, instead of sending the reply back to the ip and port where it came from. This means that the reply packets do not match the created NAT association and thus the router does not know which internal client ip and port they should be forwarded too.

Comment: I made changes to my software to ensure the correct IP and ports were bound and sent, in reverse on the return from the server, verified these addresses on the server, yet it's not getting back to the client unless I do a port forward in the router for the UDP port.  I've found also that even across the LAN, the Windows Firewall appears to block incoming replies also via UDP, but not TCP.  Is that standard practice?

Comment: I'm thinking it can't standard practice as otherwise Zoom and other UDP based communication software would not function.

Comment: @Ross: exactly, other software would not function as you've correctly observed. So it is likely something wrong with the way you handle the connections. Unfortunately there is too few known what you really do - no code, no packet capture etc. As for Windows Firewall - it depends on the configuration. But in some configurations it only allows incoming traffic only if it is in obvious response to outgoing, similar to a NAT router.

Comment: I now believe the problem is that I'm receiving the command using a UDPServer component and I'm sending the reply back using a separate UDPClient component.  There is a good reason the software is doing that, but there must be something else stored in the raw packet headers that doesn't match when I send it that way which routers and firewalls detect.  As I test I sent back a "Hello" message from the UDPServer and that is received back correctly.

Comment: @Ross: if you send the reply back from another socket it is very likely that this socket is not bound to the IP AND port of the receiver socket - which means that at least one component of the mentioned 4-tuple does not match. But again, there is no code and there are no packet captures to understand what you are really doing.

Comment: The UDPClient is being bound to the same local IP and port it received the data on, and is sending back to the same IP and port that sent the data.  I'm using Indy components in Delphi and have all 4 values available to me when the command comes in, and I've triple checked this is correct.  Also after opening the port in the router and firewall and checking the 4 values at the received end, it is also correct in the reverse order, except the destination IP is my load IP and not the public IP of course.  But I've not done any packet captures.  I'm no expert on that.

Comment: I think I will just modify the code (extensively) so I can use just the one UDPServer for receiving the text commands and sending the RTP stream. These are currently in 2 separate parts of the program. That's probably a tidier way to do it anyway.